# numpy array indexing different results ( array[:2, 2:] vs array[:2, 2] )

Tags: numpy, indexing

`array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])`

`array[:2, 2:] gives array([[3],[6]])`

`but array[:2, 2] gives array([3, 6])`

they should be the same, because both indexes to same elements.
why would actual output give different results?

Comment: Seems like you're calling the function with two different signatures: (range,range) and (range,number).

Comment: It's well documented that indexing with an integer removes a dimension.  With a slice does not.  Do you understand the result shapes?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a **range** (e.g. `[2:]`), regardless of how many elements are in that range, it will add an additional dimension.  Using a **single number** when indexing (e.g. `[2]`) "squeezes" that dimension out.  In the cases above:

1. `array[:2, 2:]` gives `array([[3], [6]])`, which has shape `(2, 1)`.  In this case, the second dimension, even just being dimension 1, is **preserved**.
2. `array[:2, 2]` gives `array([3, 6]), which has shape` (2,)`.  In this case, the second dimension is **squeezed** out.

**Note**: You can get the shape of any `np.ndarray` object using `arr.shape` and the size with `arr.size`.  Very helpful for debugging!